# NullPointerExcept for no apparent reason

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on developing a Bukkit plugin (the error is not related to bukkit or it's api, but I included the fact that I am using it for completeness, if you do not know what it is/haven't heared of it you should still be able to answer this question). The plugin I am working on is an anti chat spam plugin. I am getting a nullpointerexception for no apparent reason. Here is some code:

```
public class SpamListener implements Listener{
private HashMap<String, Long> lastMessage;
private HashMap<String, Integer> spamScore;

public void init(){
    lastMessage = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    spamScore = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
}

@EventHandler
public void playerChatEvent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
    if(AntiGrief.instance.config.getBoolean("antispam.enabled") && (!e.getPlayer().hasPermission("antigrief.spam.bypass"))){
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        String name = player.getName();
        int startingScore = spamScore.get(name); // <-- NullPointerException occurs here

        //More spam checking code here

    }
}
```

JavaPlugin class (main class, for those not familiar with bukkit):

```
    spamListener = new SpamListener();
    spamListener.init(); // <-- yes the method is being called, same error occurs if the hashmap is instantiated in the constructor and declaration
    pm.registerEvents(spamListener, instance);
```

Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/cciibpXp

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: Where did you add things to `spamScore`?

Comment: post the `Stacktrace`

Comment: Are you sure that `init` is being called before the `playerChatEvent`?

Comment: @Takendarkk Just tried it, it was the cause :).

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out.

Comment: @geoand yes I am, the playerChatEvent can only be called after pm.registerEvents(), (That function tells bukkit (a server software) about the existence of the event listener.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the problem isn't `spamScore` being `null` - it's the value in the map being null, because you haven't populated the map. You're then trying to unbox that `null` reference to an `int`, and *that* fails. So think of your code like this:

```
Integer startingScoreReference = spamScore.get(name);
int startingScore = startingScoreReference.intValue();
```

Now obviously if `startingScoreReference` is `null` (which it will be if there's no entry for `name` in your map) then the second line will cause a `NullPointerException`.

So basically you need to *either* ensure that your map will always contain an entry for `name`, or you need to handle the case where there's no such entry. For example, you might want:

```
Integer mapValue = spamScore.get(name);
int startingScore = mapValue == null ? 0 : mapValue.intValue();
```

(The `intValue()` call could be a cast to `int` instead, depending on your preference.)

Comment: Always assign to an `Integer` and then compare to null.

Comment: 7 upvotes in 5 mins. Your answer is spot on but that rep number must garner a lot of votes automatically :) (rightfully so I guess)

Comment: You shouldn't cast from YamlConfiguration.get(String) to any class you want. There's a separate method for quite every primitive type (including Strings and some Bukkit classes), so you should use YamlConfiguration.getInteger(String). Be aware that this returns null if the key doesn't exist or the value is not an Integer or String that can be parsed. Will edit the answer as soon as I get on my PC.

Comment: @flashdrive2049: I don't see any indication that my answer uses `YamlConfiguration.get()` at all. It's only calling `get` on `spamScore`, which is a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh damn, you're right. Seems like I confused this answer with an other one...